# Rails/Passenger/Nginx user permission errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, passenger

My Rails app is having trouble writing into it's `public/` directory. I've setup nginx with `user root;`, the capistrano recipe I'm using also is using `root` when connecting via ssh.

To fix this I made capistrano run `chmod o+w -R #{current_path}/` but I don't think this is a good solution. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Phusion Passenger's documentation:

> Under no circumstances will applications be run as root. If
>   environment.rb/config.ru is owned as root or by an unknown user, then
>   the Rails/Rack application will run as the user specified by
>   passenger_default_user and passenger_default_group.

http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#user_switching